# Wrong link for “Why was your post deleted?”

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, deleted-questions

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83804/shortcode-do-not-show-thumbs) (visible for mods and 10k users only) was deleted by its owner. The message under my answer looks like this:

[image]

The link goes to to our [FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). All the explanations there suggest the answerer did something wrong. The case of a question deleted by a user is not mentioned.

Request: Change that link. Link to the correct explanation.

*Side note: The **share** link is nonsense here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link shouldn't be shown on posts that didn't actually get an explicit delete vote (like answers to deleted questions) starting with the next build.